# Rounded corners on images with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I know there are jquery plugins to round the corners on divs but is there one that will work on images?

The following browsers should be supported:

- Firefox 3.0, 3.5
- IE7, 8
- Safari

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really a jQuery plugin, but this seems to do the trick: [corner.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/corner/)

Comment: Great script, does the work with minimal effort. One little inconvenience is that it uses additional css classes to actually specify the rounding parameters instead of using a function call. . Also the script does quite a bit of work with swapping the img with a canvas element and drawing but I don't see a problem here if it just works. There seem to be a additional delay before the image is rounded.

Answer (score 0):

I love [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/), and they have the answer for you... 5 different ways to do round corners, all you need to do is choose your's... because, you can't have it all ;)

> Here are FIVE different techniques you
>   can use to create rounded corners for
>   boxes on a website. There are always
>   different ways to do things with CSS
>   and rounded corners is a great example
>   of that. Each of these five techniques
>   has advantages and disadvantages.
>   Knowing all of them so you can choose
>   the perfect one in each situation is
>   the kind of thing that makes you the
>   best CSS ninja you can be!

the video can be found [in this link](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/24-rounded-corners/)

Comment: Not the kind of objective answer, but it's certainly not worth a downvote.